# OnTimeSet in onTimeSetListener not working

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have implemented a `TimePickerFragment` in a fragment. The time picker opens and I can select the time. But, the `TextView` value isn't updating even after selecting a time through `TimePickerDialog`. There are other function calls as well inside `onTimeSet` method which are also not working.

I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrpimdBRk5Q) tutorial.

Here' the code for `TimePickerFragment`:

```
public class TimerPickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getTargetFragment(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

And the Fragment inside which I'm calling the `TimePickerFragment` is as follows:

```
public class Fragment_alarm extends Fragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set Alarm");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);

        Button buttonTimePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.timeButton);
        mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);


        buttonTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimerPickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });

        Button buttonCancelAlarm = view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);

        buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        updateTimeText(c);
        startAlarm(c);
    }

    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {
        String timeText = "Alarm set for: ";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());

        mTextView.setText(timeText);
    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        ...
    }

    private void cancelAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        mTextView.setText("Alarm cancelled");
    }
}
```

The `cancelAlarm` method works fine as expected. But the other two functions which are being called from `onTimeSet` aren't working.

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of one of my alarm project.
just trigger this method at onClickEvent of the button, Hope this work for you

```
    private void addAlarm(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_alarm);
    final EditText editN = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittextALARM);
    final TextView picktime = dialog.findViewById(R.id.addAlarm_timepick);
    picktime.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                getActivity(),
                (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
                    h = hourOfDay;
                    m = minute;
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(0,0,0, h, m);a
                    //this right here maybe the answer u need
                    picktime.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendar));
                    getActiveAlarm();
                },12,0,false
        );
        timePickerDialog.updateTime(h, m);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    });
```